# Best practice for consistently cancelling Async CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cancellationtokensource

So I have a combobox on my UI that on SelectionChanged it asynchronously goes off to a web service to pull back some information to be displayed on the UI (using the new C#5 async/await keywords).  What I'm looking to do is cancel the current async request before sending a new one; for example if the user uses the keyboard to quickly cycle through all of the combobox items, the SelectionChanged event could fire multiple times (generating multiple async requests) before even the first async request returns.

So my async function that gets called from the combobox's SelectionChanged event looks like this:

```
public async Task<Connections> ConnectionsAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Connections, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Where Connections is a property that goes off and hits the web service.  So because the CancellationTokenSource cannot be reused once cancelled, I'm thinking of doing this:

```
public async Task<Connections> ConnectionsAsync()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Connections, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

The problem though is that sometimes I will be calling Cancel() when there is no async command running (e.g. the first time this function is called); so if I hookup any cancellation event handlers they will get called, even before I have made an async request.

Is there anyway to check if an async request is already running?  Other than me doing something like:

```
public async Task<Connections> ConnectionsAsync()
{
    if (_runningAsyncCommand)
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _runningAsyncCommand = true;
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Connections, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    _runningAsyncCommand = false;
}
```

I have a few async functions that all use the same CancellationTokenSource, so I would have to implement this "plumbing" in all of those functions.  Is this the best approach? Or is there a better way?

Also, if I expose _cancellationTokenSource publically so that other classes can register cancellation delegates with it, what is the best way to "transfer" these delegates over to the new CancellationTokenSource, since I'm creating a new one every time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was it resolved? I have the exact same question now.

Comment: No it wasn't resolved, but looking back on my question now I think the proper thing to do is take the CancellationTokenSource's Token as an optional parameter (i.e. public async Task<Connections> ConnectionsAsync(CancellationToken token = null)). That way the user calling the ConnectionsAsync() function is responsible for setting up a new CancellationTokenSource and passing in it's Token.

Comment: So in my example this would happen in my combobox's SelectionChanged event; I would call Cancel() on the existing CancellationTokenSource, create a new one, and pass it's Token into the ConnectionsAsync() function. In the end though for my specific application I ended up not using cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll keep looking since this is common pattern in my UI app.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a match made in heaven for Reactive Extensions. Define a throttle time that has to elapse (let's say 300mS) when observing the events from the Combobox before creating the Task

Code snippet subscribing to TextBox change events, but you'll get the idea:

```
var input (from evt in Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged")
select ((TextBox)evt.Sender).Text)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.DistinctUntilChanged();

using (input.Subscribe(inp => Console.WriteLine("You wrote: " + inp)))
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: A nice solution, but still not perfect.  Let's say my request to the web service takes 3 seconds to come back.  The user might still change the combo box selection once every 2 seconds, in which case I still have the same problem.
I don't want to set the throttle too high, for example 2 seconds, otherwise every time they change the selection there will be a 2 second delay before it even sends the request; so 5 seconds in total from the time the change the selection to the time the UI is updated.

Comment: Have you consider implementing a (pre-loaded) local cache mechanism? Do you really need to have real time data retrieval from a combobox change selection?

Comment: I *might* be able to get away with caching the data for my specific case, as there are only about 75 other people who can change the data I'm retrieving. The original question is still valid though; suppose my combobox listed my Twitter accounts, and when I selected one I wanted to see that account's live feed. This is a perfect example where you would always want real-time data.

Comment: The original question might be valid, but the specific implementation you mention is bad design. Why on earth do you want to force real time updates over the wire when the user simply switched account views through a combo box? Implement local cache for each Twitter account feed with a last updated date time field and only do service calls when that cache has expired for each account. Alternatively (even better), do periodical background updates of each stream. Try to keep things simple, your original Task implementation seem overly complicated for you specific scenario.